# Running bash commands for each JSON item through jq

Tags: json, bash, parsing, jq

I would like to run a bash command for each field in a JSON formatted piece of data by leveraging jq.

```
{
    "apps": {
        "firefox": "1.0.0",
        "ie": "1.0.1",
        "chrome": "2.0.0"
    }
}
```

Basically I want something of the sort:

```
foreach app:
   echo "$key $val"
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to list out the key/values of the `apps` object:

```
$ jq -r '.apps | to_entries[] | "\(.key)\t\(.value)"' input.json
```

To invoke another program using the output as arguments, you should get acquainted with [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs):

```
$ jq -r '...' input.json | xargs some_program
```

Comment: What if I wanted to actually run a tool against those values, ie:  `foreach app:   
   mytool $key $val   
done`

Comment: @JeffMercado a little more explanation to that comment would be most welcome. Let's say @solemnify is trying to run a command like `apt-get install ${APP} -y`. What whould the `xargs` format be?

Comment: @s.meijer: I'd say check the manpages for it. But that one should be simple. You could do something like: `jq '"filter to select package names"' input.json | xargs -i apt-get install {} -y`

Comment: Given the quoting/bracketing cruft in json this is unlikely to work as expected unless some_program takes only 1 argument.

Comment: This does seem to work, though I had to pack and unpack from an array to be able to use something like unique. You can verify with `xargs -i echo {}`. Here's an example: `jq '[.submissions[].id] | unique | .[]' ./export.json | xargs -i echo {}` which will echo each id. Luckily shell is okay with double quotes

Answer (score 5):

Here is an bash script which demonstrates a possible solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
json='
{
    "apps": {
        "firefox": "1.0.0",
        "ie": "1.0.1",
        "chrome": "2.0.0"
    }
}'

jq -M -r '
    .apps | keys[] as $k | $k, .[$k]
' <<< "$json" | \
while read -r key; read -r val; do
   echo "$key $val"
done
```

Example output

```
chrome 2.0.0
firefox 1.0.0
ie 1.0.1
```